# Middleware between Java Application/Flutter Mobile App and MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, server, middleware

I'm developing a Java desktop application and also a flutter cross-platform mobile application. I've also setup an Amazon RDS MySQL database. Instead of connecting both Java application and Flutter application to database, I want to have a middleware (not sure if it's the right word, but basically a service, which act like a broker between application and database, so they don't interact directly).

I want to set this middleware/server in AWS as well, but I don't have any knowledge and not sure what to look for and use. Just want to look for some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve.If you target simple CRUD operations than go for a api server or api gateway on aws

Comment: Yes, CRUD operations is all I want. is application server or web server a great choice?

Comment: Yes you can use a webserver